# Call css id selector to change another class

Tags: css, class, css-selectors

I've this menu in which a tab with a css id selector hide or show a div on hover but i can't call it in css.
Here i insert an example to explain better my issue: on hover 7, 8 and 9 appears.    How i have to change: `#seven:hover ~ .box`

http://jsfiddle.net/a3y52/654/

Thanks for helping out!

Comment: Please don't circumvent the quality filter. Put the code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can not achieve that in CSS. Instead, you can use `div.menu` element to trigger the hover, because this element is at the same level as the elements you want to affect:

```
.menu:hover ~ .box {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Check [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kapantzak/a3y52/653/)

**ALTERNATIVE jQuery**

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', '#seven', function() {
    $('.box').css({'display':'inline-block'});
}).on('mouseout', '#seven', function() {
    $('.box').removeAttr('style');
})
```

Comment: Ok it is right but i would to display .box only if i hover the "7" tab. (now i edit the example: [link]http://jsfiddle.net/a3y52/654/

Comment: The alternative with jQuery is good! But you haven't an alternative with pure js? Thanks.